# Get List of installed windows apps that can send notifications

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

To get all installed apps i use

```
PackageManager packageManager = new PackageManager();    
IEnumerable<Windows.ApplicationModel.Package> packages = packageManager.FindPackagesForUser("");
```

How can i filter this list to get apps (as on screenshot)?

[image]

Comment: Collected by the OS and stored under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings

Comment: Yep, But we can't load registry value directly in uwp, for loading it, you could use fulltrust desktop extension to do this.

Answer (score 0):

> Get List of installed windows apps that can send notifications

I'm afraid you can't get the app which has notification capability. Currently there is not such api could approach. And above screenshot is setting page content, and it is system level.

And currently, we could only use Notification listener to access current notification where in the action center. For more please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/notification-listener).